# null-проверка при парсинге JSON через JsonIter

Tags: java, json, null, jsoniter

```java
private static class Test {
    @JsonProperty(value = "test", collectionValueNullable = false) Long[] test;

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return Arrays.toString(test);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    String test = "{\"test\":[1,null,3]}";
    try {
        System.out.println(JsonIterator.deserialize(test, Test.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
}
```

Код не падает с ошибкой, а спокойно выводит `[1, null, 3]`. Что я делаю не так? Пробую:

```java
private static class Test {
    @JsonProperty(value = "test", collectionValueNullable = false, nullable = false) Long[] test;

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return Arrays.toString(test);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    String test = "{\"test\":null}";
    try {
        System.out.println(JsonIterator.deserialize(test, Test.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
}
```

И всё равно без ошибки выводит `null`.

Comment: В javadoc к аннотации `@JsonProperty` указано, что свойства `nullable`, `collectionValueNullable` используются ***при сериализации***: [`used in encoding only, should check null for this field`](https://github.com/json-iterator/java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jsoniter/annotation/JsonProperty.java#L51), в официальной документации примера использования я не обнаружил.  Демо из репозитория запустить не удалось из-за ошибок.  И непохоже, чтобы данная библиотека активно поддерживалась (последние обновления для Java - июль 2018)

Comment: @NowhereMan, а у меня есть какие-нибудь шансы дописать её (шансы следуя из моего уровня)? Это прям очень трудно будет? Я пытался понять как null-защита работает через `@NotNull` в JB annotations, но так и не нашёл ни одного `throw`.

Comment: Не уверен, что вам так уж необходимо дописывать эту библиотеку, в которой падает более 100 тестов, и к тому же использующую Java 6.

Comment: Можете объяснить, какой результат вы рассчитываете получить?  Чтобы выбрасывалось исключение, когда в некоторой коллекции (списке/массиве) будет записано значение `null`?

Comment: @NowhereMan, да я хочу чтоб был тот самый ParseException. и при элементе массива, и при самом элементе как `null`. Я вообще не вижу ни одного `throw`.

Comment: Тогда придётся какой-то свой десериализатор писать, чтобы быстрее было.  Валидатор не совсем подходит для такого.